# Critical exponent from powercounting of the action through the renormalization group

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, renormalization, dimensional-analysis, effective-field-theory

This will be a very basic question. For example, when we write down a $\phi^4$ action in condensed matter, let's say for an Ising magnet:
$$F[\phi] = \int d^Dx \dfrac{1}{2}(\nabla \phi)^2 + \dfrac{1}{2}t\phi^2 + \dfrac{1}{4}g\phi^4 + h\phi$$
We can read the mean field critical exponent solely from power counting of the action (that is purely from rescaling the fields + space and without integrating). For example, from the scaling of $\phi$ derived from the invariance of the kinetic term we know that the term $\int d^Dx t\phi^2/2$, especially $t$, will have a scaling dimension $\Delta_t=2$. Through (hyper)scaling relations between the exponents and by knowing $\Delta_h$ and $\Delta_t$ we can get back the critical exponents associated to every observables.
The stupid thing here is: Where did we assume mean-field? Where did we supposed that we were above the upper dimension or as we often hear that power counting discards fluctuations and that we obtain the critical exponents of the gaussian fixed point instead of, for example, the Wilson-Fisher fixed point?

Is it because we only analyzed the scaling behavior of the action/free energy without, before that, integrating the fast degrees of freedom? If that is so, I'm not sure I completely understand how this can play a role? Is it because we don't need to integrate before hand to get the right structure of the free energy if the only relevant couplings are gaussian (since fast and slow modes are uncoupled)? But once we start to have some relevant coupling, we can't simply look at the rescaling behavior of the free energy and need to integrate before rescaling?

To me, at the critical point, or close to, the free energy should be invariant by rescaling (maybe the right rescaling to do has to include the integration of fast degrees of freedom) and thus, naively, we should obtain the right critical exponents when we perform simple dimensional analysis whatever are the relevant couplings!

I'm lost!

Comment: What is $\Delta_h$ in your notation?

Comment: the scaling exponent of an eventual field! I'll update the question

Comment: My naive understanding: when we represent free energy in this form, we already imply mean-field. Two simplest examples are Ginzburg-Landau expansion for superconductor and phi-4 effective action for Ising model. May be I am wrong.

Comment: @ArtemAlexandrov In which sense do we imply mean field? Maybe my question would be clearer when reformulated as follow: why does simple rescaling gives only the critical exponent of the gaussian fixed point (equivalent to the mean field one, ie, when we assume that $\phi^4$ is irrelevant) and not the non trivial exponents of the non trivial fixed point (such as Wilson's one).

Comment: For instance, Ising model is mapped onto phi-4 model via introducing of mean-field magnetization (plays role of $\phi$) followed by truncation (which gives phi-4 theory). It seems that if you will explicitly mention the moment about Wilson-Fisher point the question will attract more attention

Comment: I see your point. I'll edit my question

Comment: Writing the free energy in this form does not imply mean-field. You obtain the mean-field free energy via saddle-point approximation of $\int D\phi \, e^{F[\phi]}$.

Comment: Completely unrelated @leapsheep but it makes me think: do you know if at equilibrium, there exists a system with some universality class that can't be derived from a free energy à la Landau-Ginzburg? That is, is there a continuous transition that can't be rationalised from expansion of the order parameter in gradients and power?

Comment: Out of equilibrium, I sometimes obtained "non equilibrium free energy" that are non analytic in order parameter = 0, with for example fractional power expansion. But is this thing possible at equilibrium?

Comment: I'm not an expert in this, you may want to ask that as a separate question.